# Can I install storm door on the door frame?

Tags: storm-door

I want to install a storm door. But my door looks a bit different: it doesn't have something called "brick module". I'm quite confused, since storm door's manual always suggests to install the storm door on the brick module.

**So my question: can I install the storm door on the part that I'm pointing at in picture 2? Is that part strong enough to hold the storm door?**

Thanks a lot!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A little more info is needed to give any good answer. I can see what would be considered "brick mold" looks like it is extruded aluminum. The frame that you point to looks like it could be painted wood, but the angle at the top tells me it may not be wood at all, or perhaps it is clad in aluminum ??

Typically the storm door jamb screws into the face of the brick mold, just as you may already know. If the surface you point to is painted wood, the storm door jamb can go there, provided there is enough room at the door handle to not interfere with the operation of the new storm door and likewise the original door.

The angle at the top I referred to earlier may complicate the storm door jamb install.

Answer (score 0):

I installed a storm door in the same situation. This door jamb has a metal molding so that the building cladding in my case its vinyl siding can be installed butted up to the door jamb. The builders don't use brick molding to save the expense of installing the trim around the door. I believe their thinking is that the door is insulated so why would you need a storm door. This is true but in the summer you have no extra ventilation from the door, plus it becomes impractical to install a pet door that will allow cold though the flap since its not sealed or insulated. If you buy two pieces of 90 degree aluminum angle you can make a 90 molding to cover the existing flange. This will allow you to attach the storm door hinge and latch railings onto the existing door jambs.

Comment: A) this is a 6 year old question (though there's no problem in answering something old). B) Your answer could use a serious dose of formatting to make it readable. _Please_ [edit] your answer to include some paragraph breaks (two `<enter>`) to break up the thoughts, and maybe even a drawing or two to help describe your solution.